# Can any moderators tell me what is going with my question?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, deleted-answers

In [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4620/the-indispensability-argument-and-impure-set-theory) question, there was at one point an answer from RParadox. I pointed out some problems with his answer and he got rather hostile. I flagged the inappropriate comments and they were removed (I presume by a moderator).

But, now for the third time, the answer from RParadox is not showing up. This pattern has been repeating, with the answer disappearing and then reappearing with a new rude comment from RParadox.

Why is the answer constantly disappearing and reappearing? Are moderators deleting it and he is restoring it? Or is he (for who knows what reason) deleting his answer and restoring it repeatedly? This whole thing has me a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His answer is being deleted and un-deleted repeatedly, and only users with sufficiently high rep can see deleted answers and questions. These actions are not being done by the same user. Presumably, there is a story behind it, which I suspect will stabilize soon.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion here. It looked like there might have been trouble afoot (vandalism or attempts to systematically delete stuff) so I restored a few questions and answers. Will let the whole thing cool down for a bit before taking any further action.

Comment: @JosephWeissman Ah ok, so am I understanding you correctly in that there was possible vandalism and you thought that his answer might have been victim to it, and so you restored it (once or twice)? And then he, or another user, noticed the answer had come back and then promptly re-deleted it?